# An acrobat of mass $m$ clings to a rope ladder hanging below a balloon of mass $M$. If the acrobat begins to climb the ladder at velocity $v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, string

An acrobat of mass $m$ clings to a rope ladder hanging below a balloon of mass $M$. If the acrobat begins to climb the ladder at velocity $v$. What is the speed with respect to Earth with which the balloon will move?

Why is momentum conserved in the $y$-direction here even though an external gravitational force is acting upon the balloon and acrobat?

Answer (score 4):

Momentum is conserved if no external force is acting.

In this case we have two external forces:

1. gravity pulling the acrobat downwards
2. buoyancy pulling the balloon upwards

Assuming the balloon and acrobat were stationary before the acrobat started climbing, the two forces are equal and opposite so the *total* external force is zero. Since the total external force is zero, momentum is conserved.